# How to create menu of overlayed divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How should I create menu like this?

[image: menu preview]

It contains of multiple square divs with different colors. After hovering on one of them the div jumps about 20px to the right (the white square). Active page's square is whole visible at it's original place (not allways on the top), others are almost hidden and only the part of them are visible.

I tried to do it with `position: absolute;` for every square but I don't know how to move all the divs below the active one after clicking on it. Any other/better ideas?

**EDIT:**
My HTML code:

```
<nav>
        <div class="nav_container">
            <li class="box1"><a n:href="Homepage:">Active</a></li>
            <li class="box2"><a n:href="Page:one">page1</a></li>
            <li class="box3"><a n:href="Page:two">Page2</a></li>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

My css code:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.nav_container {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}

nav li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li:hover {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.box1 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:rgba(153, 153, 204, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
}

.box1 a {
    color: #fff;
}

.box2 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 350px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
}

.box2 a {
    color: #fff;
}

.box3 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 400px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
}

.box3 a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: And for those who like to give me downvotes, please tell me why and what should I do to upgrade my question.

Comment: Show us your HTML markup and your CSS code. Without showing any effort, you will get downvotes.

Comment: OK, here it is, thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a basic demo of one way you could do it to get an idea and possibly develop further

it used this css

```
#nav{
    display:block;
}
#nav .right p{
    position:relative;
    top:115px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#nav .nav1{
    background:blue;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:3;
}
#nav .nav2{
    background:red;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    z-index:2
}
#nav .nav3{
    background:yellow;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    z-index:1;
}
.right{
    transition:0.5s ease;
}
.right:hover{
    margin-left:80px;
    transition:0.5s ease;
}
```

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/xset2gu2/) of it

Comment: Cool, but what if I want to set e.g. nav2 as active? Active div should be whole visible. So nav3 should have top: 60px + height of nav2. This is my main problem.

Comment: you will need to use jquery or something alike which will need a lot more work